# Gulp for loop not iterating

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, gulp

I am working on a new gulp build process and for some reason I can not get this to loop, it runs perfectly fine but it only generates the first less file so it is never iterating.

```
var files = ['style.less', 'core.less', 'theme.less']
gulp.task('build', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        return gulp.src(lessDir + files[i])
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: onError
        }))
        .pipe(less()).pipe(notify(files[i] + " Rendered!"))
        .pipe(csscomb()).pipe(notify(files[i] + " Sorted!"))
        .pipe(cssbeautify({
            indent: '  ',
            autosemicolon: true
        })).pipe(notify(files[i] + " Spaced!"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDir))
        .pipe(minifyCSS({
            keepBreaks: false,
            processImport: true,
            noAdvanced: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssminDir)).pipe(notify(files[i] + " Minified!"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` will return from the overall task, so the loop will only go through 1 iteration.

Better to specify the files in gulp.src like `gulp.src(files)` after changing files array to include your lessDir. Then let gulp's `.pipe` send each of the files through its pipeline.